# CSS :after selector with div inline-block can be shifted?

Tags: html, css

I need the disk icon to be placed more on the baseline in order to be aligned with the text and, in addition, not to increase the vertical space between lines.

[image]

The CSS code I have so far is as follows:

```
.openPage:after {
    content: ' ';
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(../rsc/home/kws.corn.icon.page.png);
}
```

Comment: Change background position... few pixels down should solve the issue....

Comment: Have you tried vertical-align:bottom; or vertical-align:text-bottom;

Comment: vertical-align: bottom; does the job! @Nillervision write the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertical-align: bottom; does the job!